# Parallelize np.searchsorted

Tags: python, numpy, numba

Is there a way to parallelize the implementation of `np.searchsorted()`?

I have a situation where the base array `a` and value array `v` are of the same order of size. From what I understand of the search sorted algorithm, it does the operation for each element in `v` in turn. I'd like to parallelize it so it performs this sorting on multiple elements of `v` at the same time. (If I have 32 cores, it should be able to sort 32 elements at once, right?) Is there a way to implement this?

I tried to use `Numba` `@jit(nopython=True, nogil=True, parallel=True)` but it shows no improvement in speed and no increase in CPU usage.

For reference, `a` and `v` are lists of integers with length on the order of 10^7 elements.

Comment: `Numba` cannot transform `numpy` functions to parallel. You'll have to find a parallel `searchsorted` function or write the code yourself. Numba can make your for loops parallel but cannot affect the code inside `numpy`.

Comment: @vahvero Numba doesn't call numpy functions, but instead has it's own replecements.  https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/main/numba/np/arraymath.py

Comment: When the two arrays are approximately of the same size, it is certainly not very efficient to use a binary search (even in parallel). A (branchless) merge can be significantly faster. This is especially true of both array are sorted. Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71298402 . Such operation can be parallelized too resulting in a much faster implementation than a binary search but this is pretty hard to implement though (not that some C/C++ library does that quite well AFAIK).

Comment: There are some alternative algorithmic approach to speed up this operation. What is the precise type of the items (eg. int32, float64)? What is the range of the values? Do you know the distribution of the values (eg. uniform, normal)?

Answer (score 2):

A trivially parallelized `np.searchsorted` works for me. Between 3.4x and 3.9x speed up on a 2-core x 2 threads colab instance with *a*, *b* length 10**7 (e.g. *9.94 s/2.62 s*) using `numba 0.55.1`, `omp` threading layer.

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def searchsorted_parallel(a, b):
    res = np.empty(len(b), np.intp)
    for i in nb.prange(len(b)):
        res[i] = np.searchsorted(a, b[i])
    return res
```

Running a micro-benchmark

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(200000, size=10**7)
b = np.random.randint(200000, size=10**7)

a.sort()

r = [0,0]
%timeit -r1 -n1 r[0] = np.searchsorted(a,b)
#1 loop, best of 1: 9.31 s per loop
%timeit -r1 -n1 r[1] = searchsorted_parallel(a,b)
#1 loop, best of 1: 2.36 s per loop

np.testing.assert_array_equal(r[0], r[1])
```